# Is there a digital analog converter with RAM?

Tags: dac

I have a didactic project that consists of making a waveform generator (triangular, sawtooth, sinosity, etc).

I have searched for a generator in an integrated circuit, but they only generate square, sine and triangle shaped waves. It doesn't allow me to create a custom periodic waveform.

I was thinking that the most logical thing is to use a DAC, but the problem is the maximum frequency that should be around 20 MHz.

This implies that in order to generate a waveform at that frequency, I would therefore have to send data to the DAC at a rate greater than 20MHz (perhaps 200MHz or more).

Obviously this could be done with a high speed device like an FPGA.

But if I want to do the same thing, but with a cheaper device, like a mid-range microcontroller, I should consider using a high-speed DAC that has an internal array of RAM.

The memory would store a data table that would be used by the DAC to generate the analog signal at its output and the microcontroller, the only thing it would do is update a table every time it wants to create a new waveform.

Maybe it's a dumb idea, but is there a DAC with those characteristics?

Any comment or suggestion is welcome

Comment: What sort of period are you thinking of -- I mean, how many samples?

Comment: Why 200MHz? Parallel DACs exist. But I doubt what you want exists because you're not asking for a DAC. You're asking for a free-looping function generator IC. Typical beginner error: Hoping an IC that does specifically everything you want exists. You could perhaps use a FIFO though and loop it onto itself.

Comment: You may be able to do it with a high speed Microchip PIC with a DAC using DMA.  There is an example paper here - https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-4AE4FCF8-7458-41A9-BF8E-958722B89989-en-US-1/index.html

Comment: @HandyHowie Yes. The idea of using DMA to control a parallel port that sends information to the DAC may be one option.

Comment: What resolution (how many bits) does your DAC need?

Comment: @FabiánRomo You can also consider making your own simple DAC with a R-2R ladder and op-amp buffer.

Comment: Instead of an FPGA, consider a CPLD, which is the low-cost version of an FPGA. Or, you might even be able to make something out of 74xxxx chips.

Comment: You can also consider using analog circuits to generate some waveforms. For example, a triangle wave is made by charging a capacitor with a current current and then discharging it with a constant current. If your MCU flips the charge/discharge switch, then it only has to do that twice per cycle. You can set your MCU to square wave mode but then insert an integrator circuit between the square wave and the output.

Comment: IIRC some of the linear tech DDS chips could be set up this way, AD9910 or such? Depends on how much RAM you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as far as I've ever seen, a DAC with integrated RAM does not exist; at least not one with enough RAM do to what you are envisioning. A DAC with a bus interface (SPI, I2C etc) might "store" at least one value, but I haven't seen one which can store hundreds or thousands of values.

Typically, outputting a periodic waveform is a pseudo-code process for a microcontroller + DAC of:

- Build a table of values in RAM
- Create a pointer, point it at the first value
- Start an interrupt timer at the chosen output frequency
- Read the value, output the value
- Increment the pointer
- If pointer is at the end, reset to the beginning
- Loop and do nothing; wait for the next timer interrupt

An alternative is to compute the next value in the free time between interrupts, if that is possible for the chosen waveform.

That said, there are several DDS or [direct-digital synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_digital_synthesis) chips out there, although these tend to be rather complex.  Can find simple DDS boards / function generators out there for very little money.  Of course, you get what you pay for.

Another somewhat-related chip were BBD or [bucket-brigade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket-brigade_device) devices. These (analog devices) work by discretely moving charge along a linear path up to 512 times.  This causes a delay from input to output, so often were found in musical instrument electronics.  So it could be argued that samples were "stored" in a BBD for some small amount of time.  Today however, this would all be done with a DSP or [digital signal processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an MCU with a internal RAM and internal DAC.

This is probably the lowest chip-count, pin-count and cost solution, if that's valuable and provided the following limitations are acceptable:

- Finding an MCU fast enough
- The quality of the internal DAC
- The planning time to get the software right, with the sample timing loop most likely written in assembler

You'd have to write a tightly-timed loop to do the following with a fixed interval:

1. Read a sample from RAM at address `pointer`.
2. Write the sample to the DAC.
3. Increment `pointer` with wraparound.
4. Padding `NOP`s etc. as needed for loop timing.
5. Loop back to step 1 if GPIO input `run` is still asserted.

An MCU with a DMA controller (DMAC) triggered by a timer would make this simpler, except for at address wraparound when the sequence interval time might be disturbed.

Your main MCU can drive GPIO input `run`, which lets it enable signal generation or stop it while the DAC MCU receives new data over, say, SPI and stores it in RAM.

All of the DAC MCU software should be a pretty short program, so it can be got correct then left alone.

Comment: The process of how to do it with an internal DAC in a microcontroller, I have a very clear idea of how I should do it.

The problem, perhaps, is that a DAC that allows me to generate a periodic signal of about 20MHz doesn't exist, or exists, but I do not think it is a cheap microcontroller.

Comment: @FabiánRomo, I'd posted this before absorbing the 200 MHz req't properly, or probably the 20 MHz one, so it's miles off as an answer :-) **I'll delete this answer shortly, after this comment exchange.** As you say, it's the DAC. MCU built-in ones are only a few Msps at best. At those speeds, an FPGA/CPLD is the right choice. None have fast-enough DACs in. I know Intel (Altera) make FPGAs with super-fast DACs for DDS but they're really big and pricey. (Haven't checked but they're bound to be, considering their target applications.) So it's a non-starter, really, unless you've deep pockets.